# Bootstrap refresh remote modal while open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3.x.x & I have a `remote` modal which is working fine, also I have Implemented the functionality where if the modal is closed, the data is flushed and a fresh ajax request is made if it is reopened. All of this is working fine.

Now I need to refresh/reload the content from that same remote URL **without closing the modal**.

Is there a way to achieve it?

One way that I can think of is just manually firing a jquery `.load` with the same URL and `modal-body` as the target. But that doesn't trigger the respective events like `loaded.bs.modal` etc.

So again, is there an official way to refresh the remote bootstrap modal, without closing it and re-opening it again?

Comment: You could try triggering those events yourself in the ajax callback using `$(selector).trigger(eventName)` Without seeing some code it's not clear what their importance is in your setup or how to refactor for both approaches

Comment: Thats one way to achieve it, which eventually I'm going to have to do anyways, I was just interested if bootstrap provides a method to achieve the same, btw, bootstrap under the hood does exactly the same by invoking the `.load()` on the `model-content` or `model-body` varying based on the version.